# Cloning a repo in Sourcetree from inside BitBucket, not all of local branches get created

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm trying to show how to clone a repo, from BitBucket into Sourcetree. I have a repo, called `test`*`help`. There are two branches in repo: `main` and `JIRA-1234`. I select the Clone button, and then select into Sourcetree. At that point, it gives me the choice of which branch to select to have cloned. I wanted all of them to be created locally. (It seems to recognize the remote version of the branch.)

To get around it, I've had to do a `git checkout <missing`*`branch>` at the CLI to get the local version of the remote branch. Should Sourcetree allow me to do this, and copy all the branches down?

Thanks,

Russ

I tried the above steps and got the above results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The branch to select is the one that will be checked out right after cloning. Nothing keeps you from changing it after with `git checkout` like you did. All the branches are accessible after a clone, no need to clone again.

Here is a link to the [Clone a repository into SourceTree](https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/clone-a-repository-into-sourcetree-780870050.html) tutorial page where you can see different methods to clone a repository. The *Method #2* seems to be the one you did:

**Step #1** - Click *Clone in SourceTree*

[image]

**Step #2** - Fill the fields and click *Clone*

[image]

As you can see in Step #2, the *master* branch will be checked out. In your case, if you wanted another branch to be checked out after cloning, you could have selected it there.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that, and see the picture now. I was just used to, when I clone a repo on the command line, a local copy of all the remote branches are created on my local side. That is what I was expecting Sourcetree would do, but I see that all the remote branches ARE there and I can check them out, creating their local counter part.

Comment: @RussUrquhart you're welcome! Even when using the command-line, you need to checkout the branches to create their local counter part. The behaviour is not different here. There is no point in creating all the local branches automatically if one is never going to check them out anyway.

Comment: @RussUrquhart note from the command line, after a clone, if you run the command `git branch` you'll see only one branch, which is the default branch that you checked out with the clone. If you run `git branch --all` you'll see that one branch plus all of the remote tracking branches, e.g. (`main`, `origin/main`, `origin/JIRA-1234`). That will be true whether you clone with SourceTree or the command line.

Comment: @TTT Oh I see. I your right. I always checked out a local copy and after awhile just thought I got all the local branches automatically! Thanks to you both!!!!